# Determine which zip codes are within defined boundary

Tags: google-maps, google-earth, zip-codes

The Antelope Valley Air Quality Management District publishes their district boundaries here:
https://avaqmd.ca.gov/district-boundaries

I need to figure out which zip codes fall within those boundaries (even if only a portion of a zip code falls within).

On their site, [they publish a Google Earth file](https://avaqmd.ca.gov/files/545d40288/MDAQMD+%26+AVAQMD+WFONA.kmz) that can be downloaded.

The following tools fall a little short because I either need to define the area myself or it only take in one address:

https://www.freemaptools.com/find-zip-codes-inside-user-defined-area.htm
https://www.randymajors.com/p/zipcodegmap.html

Given the boundary file provided by AVAQMD, what solutions are available for me to generate a list of zip codes that fall inside that boundary?